# Wildfly is keeping file using when I do Files.write

Tags: java, file, wildfly

I have two method - one to write, second to rename file:

```
public void writeToFile(File file, String content, boolean isLastLine) {
        Optional<File> optionalFile = Optional.ofNullable(file);
        if (!isLastLine)
            content += System.lineSeparator();
        try {
            Files.write(
                    optionalFile.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("File couldn't be find")).toPath(),
                    content.getBytes(),
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


public void renameFile(File fileToRename, String newFileName) {
Optional<File> optionalFile = Optional.ofNullable(fileToRename);

File finalBikFileName = new File(newFileName);

if (!optionalFile.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("File couldn't be find or doesn't exist")).renameTo(finalBikFileName)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("File couldn't be saved - already exists or some other issues");
}
}



public void renameFile(File fileToRename, String newFileName) {
    Optional<File> optionalFile = Optional.ofNullable(fileToRename);

    File finalBikFileName = new File(newFileName);

    if (!optionalFile.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("File couldn't be find or doesn't exist")).renameTo(finalBikFileName)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File couldn't be saved - already exists or some other issues");
    }
}
```

This is normal class, in application deployed on wildfly. I tested it in many ways. If I comment the write function then rename function is working proper. But if I first write something to file and then I want to rename then i got "action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program" Also i cant touch this file in windows explorer - i can't rename or delete. What can be a reason? How can I unlock it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it different threads (or server requests) that call the writeToFile and the renameFile methods? Or both methods are calling one after other under same thread/request?
2) How much data (content.length I mean) are you writing? Just want to make sure SYNC is done before the RENAME.

Comment: A few observations, let's say i have two endpoints, 1 is creating file, second is rename it. If i create file in first endpoint in second i can't rename it